# How to properly implement keep-alive connection for a C HTTP server?

Tags: c, multithreading, http, time, keep-alive

My server is implemented using edge-triggered `epoll()`.

I basically need a way to do the following:

```c
process_request(client);
client_timestamp = curr_time;

// do some other stuff, possibly call process_request(client) again and updating the timestamp

when (curr_time - client_timestamp > TIMEOUT) close(client);
```

The problems are:

1. I cannot use `sleep()` for obvious performance reasons.
2. If I use a thread to monitor each such connection, I may end up running out of threads if the number of clients grows too big.

How should I implement this?

Comment: If you have a thread per connection, then you'd normally do that with a read timeout on the socket.  Otherwise you use a `select` timeout and check for stale connections every time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I didn't understand at all, sorry. First of all, I'm using edge-triggered `epoll()` if that's relevant. Secondly, do you mean creating a separate thread for every single file descriptor and calling select on it specifically with the timeout I need? If I got that right, what do I do next? If this select timed out, do I return control to the main thread somehow signalling a timeout?

Comment: Because if that's how I described it, we still may need to create 100000 threads if 100000 clients connect simultaneously

Comment: Well, you didn't describe it, and there are several ways to write a server.   I wrote you an answer for `epoll` servers.   Unrelated: note that it's unwise to accept 100K simultaneous requests unless you expect each one to do a *lot* of blocking.  Once your CPU is 100% busy, accepting more requests just slows all of them down.  Limiting requests without limiting connections is a little tricky.

Comment: @MattTimmermans by "you didn't describe it" - do you mean that I didn't understand what you were trying to say?

Comment: No, I mean that until you edited the question, you hadn't mentioned that you were using `epoll`

Comment: @MattTimmermans `epoll_wait()` returns up to `maxevents` events, so if I have 100K clients connected and ready to perform I/O on, I will process them in chunks of size up to `maxevents` each. "Limiting requests without limiting connections is a little tricky" - what I described above should solve this issue

Comment: @MattTimmermans do you agree with the above?

Comment: No, I don't.  Actually, it sounds like you're a little bit out of your depth.  Why are you writing your own HTTP server instead of starting with a high quality open source implementation?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I do it because I've never implemented an http server and I want to do that to improve my skills

Comment: Please, explain why you don't agree with my statement and why I'd still have a lot of blocking despite handling only up to `maxevents` events at a time. I'd highly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

For an `epoll` server, you use a timeout with epoll_wait to make sure you can run code at least every few seconds, and then every time `epoll_wait` returns, after performing real work, you incrementally process connection maintenance tasks like handling various timeouts, including keep-alive.

To spread out the load, for example, keep connections in a deque.  When it's time to do maintenance, calculate the time since the last maintenance check, and then check, say `n = ceil(deque.size() * time/30s)` to make sure that each connection gets checked at least every 30s.  Move checked connections from the front to the back of the deque.

Comment: What does `n` stand for?

Comment: the number of connections to check

Comment: 1) I may need to handle timeouts like `1500 ms`, not `30s`. Is it a good idea to make a `epoll_wait` timeout of `1ms` to accurately measure timeouts? If not, what about at most `10ms`, so that I don't lose that much precision?

Comment: 2) Why do you suggest to check only `n` connections every time? How's that gonna help spread out the load? I mean, we'll have a smaller loop every time, but I don't see it as a huge performance penalty and the precision suffers if we don't check everyone

Comment: 100000 connections is a fair number to check, if you have to close a significant portion of them, and keep-alive timeouts don't have to be accurate.  This mechanism is not appropriate for short timeouts that need to be accurate.

Comment: I think it would be an even better idea to store clients in a min-heap based on a timestamp and remove up to some constant `n` clients by extracting the min element and removing it untill I get a client who's not yet timed out. What do you think?

Comment: Why do you think that's better?

Comment: Because I will have `O(1)` access to the client that's been connected for the longest time. This way I can effectively remove only the needed clients and won't search through clients that don't require removal by timeout

Comment: It works, but if your server is busy, you'll be doing more work to update the heap.  If your server is not busy, it doesn't matter.

Comment: So, what about having a lot of blocking if I have 100k connections? Why does `maxevents` not solve this? If you mean blocking due to multiple descriptors trying to send data to the server, the server shouldn't be bothered with more than `maxevents` at a time

Comment: It's not about blocking.  If your CPU is at 100% utilization, then the time required to service each request is proportional to the number of simultaneous requests, because that CPU has to be shared between all requests.

Comment: Doesn't my server do practically no work with respect to all the events not returned by `epoll_wait()`? I mean, `epoll` may have to monitor, register and schedule the events, but certainly no reading or writing occurs. It doesn't seem like a serious problem. And I see no way to avoid it, since I just have to store the events somewhere

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  So how many requests/second do you think your server will be able to handle?

Comment: I'd say that's entirely dependent on the io multiplexter and only a little bit on keep-alive. I think I'd be able to handle a few thousand/sec with my ET epoll. But what are you hinting at? Is there a way to improve my server based on something I've described?

Comment: Also, now that I thought about it, my server uses epoll in ET mode in a way I won't have much blocking. I have a state machine IO that loops through ready events and processes them in equal chunks untill all of them block. This way, I don't see how I can get some blocking interference or starvation

Comment: Again, it's not about blocking.  So lets say your server can handle 1000 request/sec.  What happens when requests come in at a rate of 1100/sec?

Comment: Some clients will wait for the response for longer than 1 sec